# How convert a dataframe to a SpatialPointsDataFrame with the same name using proj4string?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have `counties.rds` and `houses1990.rds` as data, and put them in the variables `California_shp` and `Houses`:

```
California_shp <- readRDS("counties.rds")
California_shp <- raster::aggregate(California_shp, by = "NAME")
Houses <- readRDS("houses1990.rds")
```

The information of `California_shp` and `Houses` are as follow:

```
dput(head(California_shp))
structure(list(NAME = c("Alameda", "Alpine", "Amador", "Butte", 
"Calaveras", "Colusa")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame") 

dput(head(Houses))
structure(list(houseValue = c(452600L, 358500L, 352100L, 341300L, 
342200L, 269700L), income = c(8.3252, 8.3014, 7.2574, 5.6431, 
3.8462, 4.0368), houseAge = c(41L, 21L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L), 
    rooms = c(880L, 7099L, 1467L, 1274L, 1627L, 919L), bedrooms = c(129L, 
    1106L, 190L, 235L, 280L, 213L), population = c(322L, 2401L, 
    496L, 558L, 565L, 413L), households = c(126L, 1138L, 177L, 
    219L, 259L, 193L), latitude = c(37.88, 37.86, 37.85, 37.85, 
    37.85, 37.85), longitude = c(-122.23, -122.22, -122.24, -122.25, 
    -122.25, -122.25)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

The `proj4string` of `California_shp` is also as follows:

```
California_shp@proj4string
CRS arguments:
 +proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

How by employing the `proj4string` of `California_shp` I can convert `Houses` to a SpatialPointsDataFrame with the same name?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
library(sf)
library(mapview)
houses.sf <- Houses %>%
  sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("longitude", "latitude"), crs = 4269)
mapview::mapview(houses.sf)
```

gives

[image]